# Possible to specify port in Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: javascript, cors

Problem: I have multiple apps across different subdomains, and using different ports.

Namely:

app1.crazydomain.com:123
app2.crazydomain.com:456

and I want to use app2.crazydomain.com:456 as an iFrame inside of app1.crazydoamin.com:123, which works fine. Frame loads and all is dandy.

The problem occurs when I want to make a window.postMessage(...) to app1; I'm getting CORS-blocked. Is there anyway around this?

EDIT:

To clarify a bit here, each app is a debian node server running a React JS client.

Answer (score 0):

Your crossdomain.xml can specify port constraints:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="456" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Here are some crossdomain examples:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/xdomain.html

Comment: Sorry - please see my edits. Not sure what type of config I have available, but I'd like to do it through the node server if possible.

Comment: Check out the crossdomain npm plugin if you want an easier way to do this with Node JS- https://www.npmjs.com/package/crossdomain - does that help any?